# Have a unauthorizedAccessException when using new-item

Tags: powershell

I want to use `new-item` to create a new file , but I have a  unauthorizedAccessException , it seems I can't access the path I assign

here is my code

```
$Random_Serial = Invoke-Expression .\Generate-Random-Number.ps1
Write-Host $Random_Serial
New-Item -Path ..\Database -Name "$Random_Serial" -ItemType file
```

I try to use text name to replace variable name and it can create file successfully

```
$Random_Serial = Invoke-Expression .\Generate-Random-Number.ps1
Write-Host $Random_Serial
New-Item -Path ..\Database -Name "11" -ItemType file
```

But I still can't figure out what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have security permission the the path. The output file will need an extension, and Write-Host is generally used for console output.  You can use Write-Output as an alternative. Also, Out-File is a better option than New-Item for what you are trying to accomplish.

Change

```
Write-Host $Random_Serial
New-Item -Path ..\Database -Name "11" -ItemType file
```

to:

```
write-output $Random_Serial | Out-File -Filepath C:\11.txt
```